# SQLite multiple left join query returns duplicates

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-order-by

I this SQL statement which I'm using to get questionnaire responses. The first left join in the statement is used to get the right response for the corresponding question. ( This part works fine ). The second left join in the statement I've been told gives me the ability to use the order by line. However, using this second join means that duplicates of the results are made. I need to use this line because I want the responses of the questionnaire to be given in the order (position) that the questions are in.

**SQL Tables**

```
question table:

id     position  text
name   1         who
col    3         what
reason 2         why


questionaire_responses table:

id     questionaire
uuid   uuid   
uuid   uuid   
uuid   uuid   


question_response table:

response_id  question  answer
uuid         name      sdfk
uuid         col       red
uuid         reason    why not
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT questionaire_responses.id, question_response.question, question_response.answer 
FROM question_response 
LEFT JOIN questionaire_responses ON questionaire_responses.id = question_response.responses_id 
LEFT JOIN questions ON questionaire_responses.questionaire = questions.questionaire 
WHERE questionaire_responses.questionaire = "f52ebe78-7c93-40b5-a9f0-3f20deb245ac" 
ORDER BY questions.position
```

Answer (score -1):

You almost had it right. 
You're wanting your primary limiting factor to be questionaire_responses.questionaire, but you're selecting first on questionaire_response with no limitation. 
Your query says, "Give me all the question_response rows, and, if there is one, join the questionaire_responses row that matches on responses_id. Plus add to that all questions that match on questionaire. Oh, limit the search for questionaire_responses on the questionaire uuid, but still give me all the response entries, whether or not you find a matching responses entry."
So, if you flip it around and select on questionaire_responses and join to questionaire_response, you get "Give me all the questionaire_responses rows with a matching questionaire uuid. Now join those to their corresponding questionaire_response rows." 
Here is the changed query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT questionaire_responses.id, question_response.question, question_response.answer, questions.position  
FROM question_responses 
LEFT JOIN questionaire_response ON question_response.responses_id = questionaire_responses.id 
LEFT JOIN questions ON questionaire_responses.questionaire = questions.questionaire 
WHERE questionaire_responses.questionaire = "f52ebe78-7c93-40b5-a9f0-3f20deb245ac" 
ORDER BY questions.position
```

Comment: I tried the query, but it still resulted in duplicates of the same data and it still wasn't ordered.

Comment: Yeah, left joins can be a lot of fun sometimes. 

`SELECT DISTINCT questionaire_responses.id, question_response.question, question_response.answer`

would do it - if your SQLite allows for it.  You'll probably have to add questions.position to the select list to use it in ORDER BY.